# How can I modify global variables in RShiny using button inputs from the user?

Tags: r, shiny, global-variables

I've been struggling a lot lately with the example below. In its most basic format, I have a button `some_button` and an output `result`. When the user interacts with the platform, my intention is 
to run a curve fit method (from `minpack.lm` package) and use the four parameters output from the curve fit method to initialize a `Convert()` function. In order to achieve this, my idea was to initialize an empty reactive variable for storing the coefficients (`curvefit_coeff`) and an empty `Convert()` function. Then, I use `observeEvent` with its `once` parameter set to `TRUE` ensuring that it will run only once. This one run should therefore initialize both my `curvefit_coeff`, as  well as my `Convert()` functions - I thought. However, I am unable to "take out" these values from the `observeEvent` it seems. I tried outputting them using a 
 `winDialog` and also my `result` text output but I always ended up with the following error message:

```
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)
```

```r
library(shiny)
library(minpack.lm)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("some_button", "Press me!"),
  textOutput("result")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # I tried to initialize my two variables in question as globals within the server function
  curvefit_coeff <- reactive({ })
  Convert <- function(x) { }

  # This function fits a curve and returns the four parameters of the fitted curve
  CurveFit <- function(pp) {
    ds <- data.frame("x" = c(0.01, pp, 999, 1000), "y" = c(0, 0.5, 0.999, 1))

    nlmInitial <- list(a = 0.5, power1 = -1, b = -1, power2 = 0.5)
    m <- nlsLM(y ~ a*I(x^power1) + b*I(x^power2),
               data = ds,
               start = nlmInitial,
               trace = F,
               control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 1024))

    summary(m)$coefficients[,1]
  }

  # At the very first time the button is pressed, do the curve fit and using the parameters 
  # from the curve fit, initialize the Convert() function that will be used later on
  observeEvent(input$some_button, {

    winDialog("ok", message = "Button pressed!")

    curvefit_coeff <- reactive({ CurveFit(pp = 50) })

    Convert  <- function(x) {
      (curvefit_coeff()[1])*x^(curvefit_coeff()[2]) + (curvefit_coeff()[3])*x^(curvefit_coeff()[4])
    } 

  },ignoreInit = FALSE, once = TRUE)


  # When I try to access either the coefficients from the curve fit or the Convert() 
  # function itself, I get an error:
  output$result <- curvefit_coeff()
  output$result <- Convert(3)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there's a few things going on here. First of all, if you want to display two things in the output, you should have two different output variables. Next, the error message is coming from you directly assigning a vector to the output variable(s). When you want to display what you'd normally see from running something in the console, you should be using `renderPrint` in conjunction with `textOutput`. If you do processing and have `cat`-like output, you'd want to use `renderText` instead. Finally, you don't want to be redefining `reactive` values with the assignment operator (`<-`) from within `observeEvent` - you only want to update the value (which isn't done with the assignment operator). My suggestion would be to use `reactiveValues` to track everything you need for this set of operations and output as follows.

```r
library(shiny)
library(minpack.lm)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("some_button", "Press me!"),
  textOutput("result1"),
  textOutput("result2")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # I tried to initialize my two variables in question as globals within the server function
  curve_fit <- reactiveValues(coeffs = NA,
                              Convert = function(x) return(NA))

  # This function fits a curve and returns the four parameters of the fitted curve
  CurveFit <- function(pp) {
    ds <- data.frame("x" = c(0.01, pp, 999, 1000), "y" = c(0, 0.5, 0.999, 1))

    nlmInitial <- list(a = 0.5, power1 = -1, b = -1, power2 = 0.5)
    m <- nlsLM(y ~ a*I(x^power1) + b*I(x^power2),
               data = ds,
               start = nlmInitial,
               trace = F,
               control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 1024))

    summary(m)$coefficients[,1]
  }

  # At the very first time the button is pressed, do the curve fit and using the parameters 
  # from the curve fit, initialize the Convert() function that will be used later on
  observeEvent(input$some_button, {
    curve_fit[['coeffs']] <- CurveFit(pp = 50)
  })

  observeEvent(curve_fit[['coeffs']], {
    curve_fit[['Convert']]  <- function(x) {
      (curve_fit[['coeffs']][1])*x^(curve_fit[['coeffs']][2]) + (curve_fit[['coeffs']][3])*x^(curve_fit[['coeffs']][4])
    }
  })


  # When I try to access either the coefficients from the curve fit or the Convert() 
  # function itself, I get an error:
  output$result1 <- renderPrint({
    if(all(is.na(curve_fit[['coeffs']]))) return('Button not pressed.')
    curve_fit[['coeffs']]
    })
  output$result2 <- renderPrint({
    if(is.na(curve_fit$Convert(3))) return('Button not pressed.')
    curve_fit$Convert(3)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Shiny applications not supported in static R Markdown documents

<sup>Created on 2019-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Very useful, thank you very much @ClancyStats, it was really a great help! Only one follow up question: I also want to clear the outputs using another button, so I added this snippet: 
`observeEvent(input$clear_button, {
    output$result1 <- renderPrint({ NA })
  })`

However, when I press some_button, it doesn't seem to do any fitting whatsoever. So after clearing, I am unable to get back the same values on the output(s).

(Eventually, my aim is that the user could input a value for the CurveFit function's pp argument and to do the curve fitting at every button press.)

Comment: Programming in shiny takes some getting used to - one of the major things is that you don't want to be assigning output variables in multiple places. Instead, you should have some type of `reactive` variable which holds what you want to use in the output variable. In the case above I'd say either use `observeEvent(input$clear_button, curve_fit[['coeffs']] <- NA)` or if you need to keep those coefficients around for some reason, use another reactive variable which just holds whatever you want `output$result1` to show.

Comment: Thank you very much @ClancyStats, it's all very clear now!